# Ignore KeyboardInterrupt after closing a QProcess with a CTRL_C_EVENT

Tags: python, pyqt5, qprocess

How can I ignore a KeyboardInterrupt after I used a CTRL_C_EVENT in Python? I only need CTRL_C_EVENT to close the Qprocess and not the PyQt5 window. I tried making an exception for KeyboardInterrupt but I still get the error.
I understand that CTRL_C_EVENT isn't the best option, if you want to keep PyQt5 running, however, the QProcess .exe only responds to that command. Can you help me? I made a sample code below:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from signal import CTRL_C_EVENT

class main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(main, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 800)

        self.hLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.process = QProcess()

        self.stop_btn = QPushButton('stop process')
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.finishProcess)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.stop_btn )

        self.setLayout(self.hLayout)

        path = 'C:\...\.exe'

        self.processOffline.start(path)
        self.pid = self.processOffline.processId()

    def finishProcess(self):
        os.kill(self.pid, CTRL_C_EVENT)
        try:
            self.processOffline.waitForFinished()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Still don't know why do you want to do that, I remembered QProcess has two method: `terminate` and `kill`. If you want to stop the sub process, these two method is better than you send a CTRL_C_EVENT

Comment: Kill and terminate stops the process alright. However, it doesn't exit the program cleanly meaning that the file I want to save from the process is not saving probably. The file saving only responds to a ctrl c command